# Flot tick labels use font-size: smaller which breaks their position

Tags: margin, flot, font-size, label

I'm using Flot horizontal bar chart.
The labels of the bars have `font-size: smaller` - inherited from the containing `<div class="flot-text">` which holds the labels.

This breaks the positioning of the labels:
[![Flot bar chart Broken labels][1]][1]

So I need to do this

```
$(".tagChart .flot-text").css("font-size", ""); // Flot uses "smaller" which breaks alignment.
```

Which is a bit hacky. This doesn't work:

```
            yaxis: {
                // Otherwise Flot uses "smaller" which breaks alignment.
                //font: { size: "14px", color: "black" }, // doesn't work
            },
```

How am I supposed to prevent that `smaller` from being added? Also, interesting thing is that it doesn't appear elsewhere in the page in different DOM/CSS context.

EDIT: It seems that it could have something in common with Bootstrap's CSS rule which is inherited by its content:

```
table { font-size: 12; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep all the label in same width(display:inline-block). Use text align right to align it on the same line

Comment: That won't help much as Flot is placing the labels using position: absolute and top: and left: . It's already aligned to right.